# How to rewrite a QML timeline in C++ using the QTimeLine class?

Tags: c++, qml, timeline

I have created this timeline with Qt Design Studio and it works well, but since I want to control the timeline with C++, I need to use the [QTimeLine class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeline.html).

```
Timeline {
    id: timeline
    animations: [
        TimelineAnimation {
            id: timelineAnimation
            duration: 1000
            loops: 0
            running: true
            to: 1000
            from: 0
        }
    ]
    endFrame: 1000
    startFrame: 0
    enabled: true
    KeyframeGroup {
        target: image
        property: "scale"
        Keyframe {
            value: 1.25
            frame: 100
        }
        Keyframe {
            value: 1
            frame: 1000
        }
    }
}
```

So I have exposed the scale property of the image like this.

```
#ifndef SCALER_H
#define SCALER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimeLine>
#include <qqml.h>

class Scaler: public QObject{

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant scale READ scale WRITE setScale NOTIFY scaleChanged)
    QVariant m_scale;

public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    QVariant scale() const{
        return m_scale;
    }

public slots:
    void setScale(QVariant scale){
        if (m_scale == scale)
            return;
        m_scale = scale;
        emit scaleChanged(m_scale);
    }

signals:
    void scaleChanged(QVariant scale);
};

#endif // SCALER_H
```

connecting the property with

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("scaler", &scaler);
```

and changing the scale property to scaler.scaler

```
Image {
    id: img1
    x: 139
    y: 46
    width: 159
    height: 234
    source: "images/image.svg"
    scale: scaler.scale
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    }
```

This works so far. Now I need to rewrite the QML version of the animation above using the API provided by the QTimeLine class. Using [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimeline.html#details) I can scale up the image endlessly, but I don't see methods for setting the keyframes etc. How do you go about this? Can I maybe trigger the timeline I have already created in QML?

```
Scaler scaler;
timeline = new QTimeLine(1000, engine.rootContext());
timeline->setFrameRange(0, 100);
QObject::connect(timeline, &QTimeLine::frameChanged, &scaler, &scaler::setScale);
timeline->start();
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on this topic, but just from a quick look at the docs, I'd say that despite their similar names, QML's `Timeline` and `QTimeline` are not the same thing. QML's Timeline appears to have a lot more functionality that's not present in the simple QTimeline class (like keyframes, etc.). You should probably be looking at the QQuickTimeline source code for an understanding of the C++ side.

Comment: Okay thanks. I actually just got it to work by exposing the attributes of the QML timeline. This works fine for me so far.